# What if my Internet Service Provider decides not to let me send bitcoins?

Tags: network, ownership

Since bitcoins are sent through the internet, what would happen if my Internet Service Provider prevented me from sending bitcoins?  If they can do that, does that mean that I don't really control my bitcoins?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Since bitcoins are sent through the internet, what would happen if my Internet Service Provider prevented me from sending bitcoins?

There really is no practical technical way to do this, but they could just have a rule.

> If they can do that, does that mean that I don't really control my bitcoins?

No, since you choose your ISP.

Answer (score 2):

You can write Bitcoin transaction data on USB stick using your private key.

Then you go to a Internet provider or country where they do not block connecting to Bitcoin nodes.

Comment: Indeed. You can also set up a server elsewhere or ask a friend to help you, such that you tunnel your Bitcoin transactions over another protocol like HTTPS.

Answer (score -1):

Easy! Use Tor, or any VPN service. Problem solved! The ISP can't monitor encrypted traffic.